# Pandas- Create a new column filled with the number of observations in another column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a DataFrame object `df`.  One of the column values in `df` is `ID`  There are many rows with the same ID.

I want to create a new columns `num_totals` that counts the number of observation for each ID.   For example, something like this:

```
ID | Num Totals
1  |    3
1  |    3
1  |    3
2  |    2
2  |    2
3  |    3
3  |    3
3  |    3
4  |    1
```

What's the fastest way to do this in Pandas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A simple groupby+transform would work:

```
df['num_totals'] = df.groupby('ID').transform('count')
```

Comment: Got it.  Brand new to PANDAS, and I wasn't sure if that would add the totals to each row in ID or just one of them.

Comment: If you would use `.count()` or `.agg('count')` instead of `transform()` it would indeed collapse to the amount of unique ID's. But transform reshapes the result to the original dimension.

Comment: Got it, then transform is what I need.  Thanks!