# Why Pandas Transform fails if you only have a single column

Tags: python, pandas

After looking at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19265942/pandas-create-a-new-column-filled-with-the-number-of-observations-in-another-co) I did some messing about and found this:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,1,1,1,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,4,4,4]})
df['num_totals'] = df.groupby('a').transform('count')

gives ValueError:

ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-38-157c6339ad93> in <module>()
      3 #df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,1,1,1,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,4,4,4], 'b':[1,1,1,1,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,4,4,4]})
      4 df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,1,1,1,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,4,4,4]})
----> 5 df['num_totals'] = df.groupby('a').transform('count')
      6 
      7 #df['num_totals']=df.groupby('a')[['a']].transform('count')

C:\WinPython-64bit-2.7.5.3\python-2.7.5.amd64\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.pyc in __setitem__(self, key, value)
   2117         else:
   2118             # set column
-> 2119             self._set_item(key, value)
   2120 
   2121     def _setitem_slice(self, key, value):

C:\WinPython-64bit-2.7.5.3\python-2.7.5.amd64\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.pyc in _set_item(self, key, value)
   2164         """
   2165         value = self._sanitize_column(key, value)
-> 2166         NDFrame._set_item(self, key, value)
   2167 
   2168     def insert(self, loc, column, value, allow_duplicates=False):

C:\WinPython-64bit-2.7.5.3\python-2.7.5.amd64\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.pyc in _set_item(self, key, value)
    677 
    678     def _set_item(self, key, value):
--> 679         self._data.set(key, value)
    680         self._clear_item_cache()
    681 

C:\WinPython-64bit-2.7.5.3\python-2.7.5.amd64\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals.pyc in set(self, item, value)
   1779         except KeyError:
   1780             # insert at end
-> 1781             self.insert(len(self.items), item, value)
   1782 
   1783         self._known_consolidated = False

C:\WinPython-64bit-2.7.5.3\python-2.7.5.amd64\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals.pyc in insert(self, loc, item, value, allow_duplicates)
   1793 
   1794             # new block
-> 1795             self._add_new_block(item, value, loc=loc)
   1796 
   1797         except:

C:\WinPython-64bit-2.7.5.3\python-2.7.5.amd64\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals.pyc in _add_new_block(self, item, value, loc)
   1909             loc = self.items.get_loc(item)
   1910         new_block = make_block(value, self.items[loc:loc + 1].copy(),
-> 1911                                self.items, fastpath=True)
   1912         self.blocks.append(new_block)
   1913 

C:\WinPython-64bit-2.7.5.3\python-2.7.5.amd64\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals.pyc in make_block(values, items, ref_items, klass, fastpath, placement)
    964             klass = ObjectBlock
    965 
--> 966     return klass(values, items, ref_items, ndim=values.ndim, fastpath=fastpath, placement=placement)
    967 
    968 # TODO: flexible with index=None and/or items=None

C:\WinPython-64bit-2.7.5.3\python-2.7.5.amd64\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals.pyc in __init__(self, values, items, ref_items, ndim, fastpath, placement)
     42         if len(items) != len(values):
     43             raise ValueError('Wrong number of items passed %d, indices imply %d'
---> 44                              % (len(items), len(values)))
     45 
     46         self.set_ref_locs(placement)

ValueError: Wrong number of items passed 1, indices imply 0
```

But if I have 2 columns then it works fine:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':1,1,1,1,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,4,4,4],'b':1,1,1,1,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,4,4,4]})
df['num_totals'] = df.groupby('a').transform('count')
df



Out[40]:
    a  b  num_totals
0   1  1           4
1   1  1           4
2   1  1           4
3   1  1           4
4   2  2           2
5   2  2           2
6   3  3           3
7   3  3           3
8   3  3           3
9   4  4           7
10  4  4           7
11  4  4           7
12  4  4           7
13  4  4           7
14  4  4           7
15  4  4           7
```

or if I do this using a single column df:

```
df['num_totals']=df.groupby('a')[['a']].transform('count')
```

There is a similar [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13854476/pandas-transform-doesnt-work-sorting-groupby-output) but it is unclear to me why a series should fail and a dataframe should work in the immediate above example, and why having 2 or more columns would work.

I am using Python 2.7 64-bit and Pandas 0.12

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### Single Column in the DF

As you noted above, this returns a series the same size as the original

```
In [32]: df.groupby('a')['a'].transform('count')
Out[32]: 
0     4
1     4
2     4
3     4
4     2
5     2
6     3
7     3
8     3
9     7
10    7
11    7
12    7
13    7
14    7
15    7
Name: a, dtype: int64
```

However, this is returing an empty frame

```
In [33]: df.groupby('a').transform('count')
Out[33]: 
Empty DataFrame
Columns: []
Index: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15]
```

you cannot assign a an empty frame as a column to another frame because this is essentially an ambiguous assignment (you can make a case that it should 'work' though)

### Two columns in the starting DF

The two column case return a single-column DataFrame

```
In [42]: df2.groupby('a').transform('count')
Out[42]: 
    b
0   4
1   4
2   4
3   4
4   2
5   2
6   3
7   3
8   3
9   7
10  7
11  7
12  7
13  7
14  7
15  7

In [43]: type(df2.groupby('a').transform('count'))
Out[43]: pandas.core.frame.DataFrame

Or a series

In [45]: df2.groupby('a')['a'].transform('count')
Out[45]: 
0     4
1     4
2     4
3     4
4     2
5     2
6     3
7     3
8     3
9     7
10    7
11    7
12    7
13    7
14    7
15    7
Name: a, dtype: int64

In [46]: type(df.groupby('a')['a'].transform('count'))
Out[46]: pandas.core.series.Series
```

This 'works' because pandas DOES allow assignment of a single column frame to work, as it will take the underlying series.

So pandas is actually trying to be helpful. That said, I find this an unclear error message for trying to assign an empty frame.

Comment: Yes I did notice the empty frame in the single column version, I guess the issue is the ambiguous error message, thanks for the clarification

Comment: It might be nice for groupby to have a keyword which keeps the column used for grouping available to the functions. Its still in the groups, so why not letting a function being applied to it? If a lambda works, why not the 'usual' functions. Something like this works for a single column df.groupby:
`df['a'].map(df.groupby('a').apply(lambda x: len(x)))`

Comment: To explain the syntax of df.groupby('a')['a'].transform('count'): ('a') is what you group on and ['a'] is what you count. It may seem obvious but certainly was not for me :) It is easier to see with e.g. df.groupby('city')['number-of-people'].transform('sum').