# Groupby.transform doesn't work in dask dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, dask

i'm using the following dask.dataframe `AID`:

```
   AID FID  ANumOfF
0    1   X        1
1    1   Y        5
2    2   Z        6
3    2   A        1
4    2   X       11
5    2   B       18
```

I know in a pandas dataframe I could use:

```
AID.groupby('AID')['ANumOfF'].transform('sum')
```

to get:

```
0     6
1     6
2    36
3    36
4    36
5    36
```

I want to use the same with dask.dataframes which usually uses same functions as a pandas dataframe, but in this instance gives me the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'SeriesGroupBy' object has no attribute 'transform'
```

It could either be one of two things, either that dask doesn't support it, or it's because I'm using python 3?

I tried the following code:

```
AID.groupby('AID')['ANumOfF'].sum()
```

but that just gives me the sum of each group like this:

```
AID
1     6
2    36
```

I need it to be as the above where a sum is repeated in each row. My question is, if transform isn't supported, is there another way I could achieve the same result?

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19267029/why-pandas-transform-fails-if-you-only-have-a-single-column

Comment: Hi Ed, in the link it says that the above should work in you have two columns, and I do have two columns and it does work with a pandas dataframe. My issue is that I have a dask dataframe, which doesn't seem to support transform. Is there a way to achieve what transform does without using transform?

Comment: I've no experience with dask dfs, does this work: `AID.groupby('AID')[['ANumOfF']].transform('sum')`? this in pandas land would force a single column df to be called

Comment: As of April 2017, Dask.dataframe groupby objects do not support the transform method.  You may want to [raise an issue](https://github.com/dask/dask/issues/new) to request it.

Comment: EdChum, this works in pandas dataframe yes. But my data is so large I can't use pandas, and therefore have switched to dask.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think you can use [`join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.join.html):

```
s = AID.groupby('AID')['ANumOfF'].sum()
AID = AID.set_index('AID').drop('ANumOfF', axis=1).join(s).reset_index()
print (AID)
   AID FID  ANumOfF
0    1   X        6
1    1   Y        6
2    2   Z       36
3    2   A       36
4    2   X       36
5    2   B       36
```

Or faster solution with [`map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.map.html) by aggregate `Series` or `dict`:

```
s = AID.groupby('AID')['ANumOfF'].sum()
#a bit faster
#s = AID.groupby('AID')['ANumOfF'].sum().to_dict()
AID['ANumOfF'] = AID['AID'].map(s)
print (AID)
   AID FID  ANumOfF
0    1   X        6
1    1   Y        6
2    2   Z       36
3    2   A       36
4    2   X       36
5    2   B       36
```

Comment: Do you know how to map the results back to the dataframe for a multi-column groupby? I'd be happy to open this as another question if you think that's appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

Currently `Dask` [supports transform](https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/dataframe-api.html?highlight=transform#dask.dataframe.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform) , howerver there may be an issues with indexes (depending on original dataframe). [see this PR #5327](https://github.com/dask/dask/pull/5327)

So your code should work

> AID.groupby('AID')['ANumOfF'].transform('sum')